# How to stream a presigned video from an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video, streaming, mp4

When generating a presigned video URL from AWS S3 bucket the video will download in mp4 format if I use the URL in the web browser , however, it will not stream if I put it in the src attribute of a video tag. Below is an example of what the presigned url looks like. How can I use this url to stream?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls preload="auto">
  <source src="https://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/daycare.videos/iland-guard/yamit/2020-12-09/cam_0/20201209_043123.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA6OHOPCC5DWJXXO7O%2F20210309%2Feu-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210309T075948Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=1cfb2dc7658b90714cd5b52b157f3caf878be6504a4d5f9d1a1be76a599abae8&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: If you temporarily make the object public and then use the same code to reference the object (without the parts after the `?`), does it stream successfully?

Comment: Yes it streams successfully if public and not using the presigned configurations. The idea however is to stream it while presigned.

Comment: Well, that certainly suggests that the pre-signed URL is the problem. What happens if you put the complete URL in the Address bar of a browser? Does it say "Access Denied"?

Comment: No, then it downloads the video in mp4 format, however when putting the url in the videotag src attribute nothing streams

Comment: How did you generate this pre-signed URL? It comes out in a different format to what the AWS CLI produces.

Comment: I am not using the asw cli. I am using Node

Comment: const url = s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", signedParams);

Comment: That URL looks like it might be an older signature method. I wonder whether you are using the latest Node SDK? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-sigv2-deprecation-period-extended-modified/

Comment: I am using the latest sdk, I just edited above the actual code so maybe you can replicate...thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To test this, I did the following:

- Put an `.mp4` file in an Amazon S3 bucket (no Bucket Policy, no ACL)
- Generated a pre-signed url using the AWS CLI `aws s3 presign` command
- Tested the pre-signed URL by pasting it into a browser Address Bar -- it worked
- Substituted the pre-signed URL in your code (above) -- it worked

I did have a strange problem with a space in the filename -- I had to quote the path for the AWS CLI to include the raw space rather than using a `+` to represent the space.

The pre-signed URL that was generated looked like this:

```
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/A2%20File.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAxxx&Signature=xxx&Expires=1615413373
```

I see that it uses a different format to the one presented in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated above, using the Node library. The code seems to work fine. The key thing to make sure is whether the presigned URL works when placed in your browser. The SDK generates a URL regardless of whether the file exists or not, so make sure the presigned URL is actually functioning.

The format of my presigned URL matches that of yours:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="https://bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/Glass%20one/2e71b368-1d22-4c56-a690-b534eea3def8.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQOTARPS7GGSVO5F7%2F20210915%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210915T223104Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=f61fc82b7ebd55ea83290587786d61fe41cb6137624d243bf36c46257ef2aab6&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things:

1. Go to S3 console and select your file.
2. Go to `Action` , after that click `Edit metadata` and type the Metadata value as `video/mp4` and save changes and go back.
3. Go to `Action` after that click `Share with a presigned URL` and create Presinged URL.

**or** if you use NodeJs

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: xxx,
        secretAccessKey: xxx,
        region: xxx,
        signatureVersion: xxx,
        Expires: 120,
      });

      const params = {
        Key: xxx,
        Bucket: xxx,
        ResponseContentType: `video/mp4`,
      };
      const url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
          err ? reject(err) : resolve(url);
        });
      });
```

This is work for me